# How to pass color dynamically in dynamic layout?

Tags: android, background-color

I am creating a dynamic layout using following code,

```
LinearLayout outerLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(activity);
outerLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

As you can see I am setting its background color to white, now suppose I have array of string which contains element like { "#FF2233", ... } then How can I pass this hexadecimal value to `setBackgroundColor()` dynamically ?

My motive is to pass dynamic color value at run time rather than passing a fix value like `Color.WHITE`.

Comment: the answer is given please have a look . hope will help you!! (+1) for this question , and interesting one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use the Color class, this class has a method to parse colors in hex to Android valid values.

```
Color.parseColor("#FF2233");
```

Comment: Excellent,, that's the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

the value of color are integer so it can be use as a string than can be converted to int again

```
int color = Integer.parseInt("bdbdbd", 16)+0xFF000000;
```

and use this color according to yours need

or directly you can so like `Color.parseColor("yours color value");`

by means

You can parse the HEX String value into Color and use like

int color = Integer.parseInt("bdbdbd", 16)+0xFF000000; 
as

```
 LinearLayout outerLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(activity); outerLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(color )
```

or use Color.parseColor("yours color value") 
as

```
 LinearLayout outerLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(activity); outerLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("yours color value"))
```

Comment: I am not getting how your code works, can you explain it please ?

Comment: hi You can parse your HEX String into Color and load like wither int color = Integer.parseInt("bdbdbd", 16)+0xFF000000; or Color.parseColor("yours color value") as LinearLayout outerLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(activity);

 outerLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("yours color value"));

Comment: oh, you are converting string to hex ising Integer.parInt(). How come I forgot this. This is nice a way too. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. You just parse your `HEX String` into `Color` and load like:

```
 LinearLayout outerLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(activity);

 outerLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#101010"));
```

And `Color.parseColor("#"+your color value)` passed

Comment: Havent I mentioned that It is dynamic layout.